# Binding Click action to custom xaml component

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have the following custom control in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="170">
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE188;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Visibility="{Binding isFolder, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="&#xE113;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Foreground="Gold" Visibility="{Binding isFolder, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Margin="5,0" Foreground="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

I want to bind click action on isFolder. So I created a xaml page and in code behind I added the control as follow:

```
        MyControl item = new MyControl();
        item.DataContext = context;
        // item.click += context.isFolder ? folderAction : nonFolderAction
```

There is no item.click. How can I add delegate to click based on boolean value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relaycommands where you can specify the condition when the command should be executed.

For example: (in your case)

In your viewmodel: (do this)

```
    private RelayCommand myCommandInViewModel;

    public RelayCommand MyCommandInViewModel
    {
        get { return myCommandInViewModel?? (myCommandInViewModel= new RelayCommand(myCommandInViewModelAction,()=> { return isFolder; })); }
    }
```

where  myCommandInViewModelAction has your method definition.

Above is the advised way of doing.
Else you can have another way where in the button.Click event you can get the datacontext of the sender and check for isFolder property in it.

```
private void someClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     var buttonDataContext = (sender as Button).DataContext;
     if(buttonDataContext.isFolder)
     {
       doSomeThing();
     }
     else
     {
     return;
    }
    }
```